# How to check number is available in CString - Visual MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

There is an edit control (Type: CString)  in my program. How to check if this control contains any number? (ex: "abcdef4hg", "xxxyyy12"....)

Comment: Read about [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to check if there is a digit in the string or not. You can use `std::isdigit`.

```
#include <cctype>

bool hasDigits(const CString &str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.GetLength(); i++)
    {
        if(std::isdigit(str[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```